# how to remove element from LinkedList<Integer> array[]

Tags: java, arrays

```
LinkedList<INteger> ar[4];

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    ar[i]=new LinkedList();
}

ar[0].add(99);
ar[1].add(60);
ar[0].add(66);
ar[0].add(61);

// how to remove 66 from List 0 index
ar[0].remove(66);
//but this above statement shows error
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 1
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.remove(Unknown Source)

Comment: That doesn't look right. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: this is the only error i get brother.

Comment: I didn't deny it. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Java thinks the 66 you are passing in to the method `ar[0].remove(66);` is an index, not the object, so you need to get the index of the object first.

```
int index = ar[0].indexOf(66);
ar[0].remove(index);
```

Comment: Well I have one more question when passing linked list in functions java passes it by call by reference right how to pass it without reference

Comment: Java always passes by value, not reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617827/when-i-use-linkedlist-in-java-it-seems-not-to-pass-by-value-anymore-anyone-c

Comment: So to clarify, when you pass an object variable into a method, you are passing in a pointer to the object. Inside the method, the variable in the method signature has a copy of the pointer, not the object, so when you mutate a property of the object, it is seen outside of the method. If this is not what you want, you need to clone your object.

Comment: even the cloning is also not working for LinkedList i dont know why

Comment: If this question is answered, then you should mark it so, and start a new question if you are having another problem.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two types passed as an argument to `LinkedList#remove`:

1. an `int` (which is considered the index of the element to be removed).
2. an `Integer` (which is considered the value of the element to be removed).

```
// remove 66 by index
int index = ar[0].indexOf(66);
if (index > -1) // if it exists
   ar[0].remove(index);
System.out.println(ar[0]); // => [99, 61]

// remove 66 by value
ar[0].remove(new Integer(66));
System.out.println(ar[0]); // => [99, 61]
```